# Конвертация данных в PL/SQL

Tags: дата, plsql, char, конвертация

Есть два запроса, связанные `UNION`, выдающие результат в формате `char`, необходимо их сложить.

Результаты выглядят в виде времени, например, `"00:02:55"` и `"01:44:01"`. Как их сложить?

При попытке обычного сложения выдает ошибку:

> "Invalid number"

Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t as (
  select '00:02:55' some_time from dual union all
  select '01:44:01' from dual
  )
select numtodsinterval(sum(to_char(to_date(some_time,'hh24:mi:ss'),'sssss')),'second') total_time
from t
```

результат:

| TOTAL_TIME |
| --- |
| +000000000 01:46:56.000000000 |

---

UPD:
Если нужна меньшая точность, можно конвертировать:

```
with t as (
  select '00:02:55' some_time from dual union all
  select '01:44:01' from dual
  )
select cast(numtodsinterval(sum(to_char(to_date(some_time,'hh24:mi:ss'),'sssss')),'second') as interval day(2) to second(0)) total_time
from t
```

результат:

| TOTAL_TIME |
| --- |
| +00 01:46:56 |

Comment: В целом, работает, спасибо, но только почему так много нулей? 
У меня результат получился "+000000000 01:46:56.000000000"

Comment: @tennant993, это стандартный формат, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает, вопрос можно, в целом, закрывать. 
Однако, в идеале, чтобы выводилась сумма вне рамок формата 24 часа. То есть, чтобы не "+01 01:46:56", а "25:46:56". Если так можно, было бы идеально.